# Which view is responsible of rendering `successful installation` page?

Tags: django

I just installed the django and created a new project called api.

now in `api.api.urls` there is the default:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

so there is url pattern for the admin site, but where is the url pattern for the home page (the page with the rocket) and which view is responsible for rendering it?

EDIT:

after doing some research i accidentally found the template in `django.views.templates` it is called `default_urlcont.html`.
but that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: You need to refresh your Django knowledge with [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01/) and Django rest with [rest tutorial](https://realpython.com/django-rest-framework-quick-start/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django shows the successful installation page if `DEBUG` is set to `True` in your settings and you didn't provide any custom url pattern. So to override the default behavior you need to define a pattern, for example:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from .views import your_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', your_view),
]
```

This [view](https://github.com/django/django/blob/5cc9464e4d8fe2762e462560665fd1f28104bbca/django/views/debug.py#L556) is responsible of rendering that page.